# How to choose only required fields from a returned json object and to store it in the predefined RestultObject

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, es6-modules, octokit-js

I am using octokit in my typescript project. when I do octokit.request(any_endpoint), it is returning the object of OctokitResponse and it has some fields that are unnecessary for me, but i have to store it in any type. Like when I retrieve all the repos and I just want repo name from the response. How to do that.
I want some similar thing to dotnet efcore select() method to select required data only. I dont know is there the pojo classes octokit is offering to store the result.

```
        let res: OctokitResponse<any> = await octokit.request('GET /orgs/{org}/repos', {
                org: configData.organizationName,
                type: 'all',
                headers: {
                    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
                },
                per_page: perPage,
                page: page
            });
```

I want some custom type to use instead any. Let me know it Octokit is offering pojo classes to store the response directly writing instead on any.
basically I want to remove responsetype as any.
Thank you.

Comment: Haven't used Octokit but they should provide a generic type on their request method.
Have you tried `await octokit.request<OctokitResponse<MyType>>('GET /orgs/{org}/repos',{...})`

Comment: yes, I have tried it. and it is working fine but actually It will do kindof some checks that the field define in MyType must be there in the response. Although it is returning the whole response object rather than the field define in MyType.

Comment: Typescript will not actually filter out properties that you don't describe in your type. Unless the library utilizes the type to filter out unneeded types then you need to do this manually or by using a library to pick the properties you need.

Comment: Yes, Octokit will only check for the existence of the properties described in the given type, but not filter out only those properties and give only that much short response. It will still give all the fields in response, So I think It is necessary that I have to use map function to map the property of the array response.